# terminator terminal horizontal scroll

Tags: ubuntu, scroll, terminal, terminator

I did not manage to scroll horizontally on Terminator Terminal on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

In it's man page there is no screen buffer size(width like Windows cmd) size or horizontal scroll settings.

What should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminator terminal in Ubuntu repository is not same with the link below.

[https://github.com/software-jessies-org/jessies/wiki/Terminator][1]

It provides horizontal scrolling.

Comment: I made a terrible mess out of my system trying to remove the jessies disaster multiplied by a typo. Horizontal scrolling would be wonderful, but I now believe in setterm -linewrap on/off and/or tput rmam/smam. Some things just are not worth the cost.

Comment: What was the cost :)?

Comment: apt-get refused to reinstall Debian terminator after purge and deletion of all terminator*. I reinstalled the entire OS just to recover the Debian terminator. Jessies terminator, felt very rough and strange and desired ancient java version 8.

I made errors during manual backup before manual removal which resulted in loss of wanted data and code. Recovery to the 'new' OS (not sid), revealed backup holes. Fortunately, .emacs.d/backup/ contains much wanted data.

Cost: Up all night and still restoring. I gained comfort for Debian terminator, am making better backups, and have a clean system.

Comment: Do you remember what was the error when you try to reinstall? Yeah, there are strange requirements to install some software. At least you got what you what(partially). Thanks to backups which we do not know they exist :).

Comment: Apt did not produce any error. I should have apt-get clean. Make created a deb file and dpkg install must have copied the deb file into /var/cache/apt causing apt to only see the unwanted package. Hind sight is 20/20. :)